# Can't access VS2008 toolset from VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, platform

Could anyone help me with my really simple situation?

- I installed VS2008 (Professional)
- Updated to SP1
- Installed other updates offered by Windwos Update
- Installed VS2013 (Update 2 Ultimate)

After that I made a new project, opened projects and I was disappointed, because the following thing was shown:

http://grabilla.com/04710-36a0424a-57c7-4e35-9792-72fd6310c989.png

Could anyone help me what should I do now? I have VS2008 installed, but it doesn't show up on the platform toolset list. Do you have to set something? Did I make something wrong?

Thank you for your help guys! :)

Comment: Wasn't it only VS2010 and newer that had that functionality?  I don't think you can use the 2008 toolset remotely like that...

Comment: Nope, [this page](http://blog.iangoodsell.com/2010/04/visual-studio-2010-and-platform-toolset.html) says 2010 should be able to use the 2008 toolset.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773299/vs2012-has-no-option-to-select-vc90

Comment: Oh, then I need VS2010 too. Could you please tell me if installing VS2010 now will corrupt any thing, or can I safely install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved via Installing VS2010 too. To have VS2008 toolset you need VS2008, VS2010 (and in my case:) VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use (in a supported way) the VS2008 Tool chain in VS2013.

There are some tricks that maybe work, i tested with VS2010, executing the VS2008 version of *vcvarsall.bat* (the file containing the environment variables to set for Visual Studio to find the tools) before loading VS and when load it use the VS2008 Tool Chain, I don't recommended the intellisense would be out of sync and might be other problems.

Comment: Have a source for that?

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I have vc90 toolset any other way? I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: For the method? I tested with VS2010, of course is not a supported method, but when i was investigating the same find it in a blogpost  and tested and it work. It's easy tested in VS2013, open a cmd (no an VS cmd, normal cmd), execute vcvarsall.bat, execute devenv.exe from VS2013 folder, open project and compile (should see the compiler version in the output windows), i don't remember if i need to update or create projects for vs2010.

Comment: You could make the same that [clang toolchain](http://llvm.org/builds/downloads/LLVM-3.5.r212716-win32.exe) did for VS2013 integration (probably could be easier using vs2008 toolchain existing files, at least for start)

Comment: So, execute VS2008 vcvarsall.bat, then execute devenv.exe from VS2013.

What is it exactly going to do?

Comment: I tried to execute that bat file, after that I ran VS2013, made a new project, compiled it, but it still compiled with the 2013 compiler.

Comment: Some fixes to the procedure, tomorrow i will tested with VS2008 and VS2013. Create a .bat file. Call `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat`. Call `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com /useenv`. Note **/useenv** parameters. This tell devenv that use the environment version of the variables needed and no the hardcoded versions. Execute the .bat.

Comment: Tested, when executed using the previous procedure, the tools chain used in VS2013 is the VS2008 version. You could not changed in the Toolchain select menu, it would be using VS2008 version for default.